# Get Object type from in CosmosDB ChangefeedObserver Document

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a project that needs to monitor a number of collections within a number of cosmosDB's with the CosmosDB Change Feed.

The signature for the ChangeFeedObserver is pretty explicit, to where I'm not clear on how I can pass in the object type that the ComosDb.Document (in json format) represents.

```
public Task ProcessChangesAsync(IChangeFeedObserverContext context, IReadOnlyList<Document> deltas, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

due to this, I have a series of Observers with only a single word thats different.  The name of the class that gets passed to processing.

```
DocumentObserverHelper.Processing<MyType>(context, deltas, cancellationToken);
```

With the type, my helper is able to deserialize and process the document.  Though now I have a number of observer classes.
eg: 
MyType1Observer.cs, MyType2Observer.cs, MyType3Observer.cs, MyType4Observer.cs

All classes share the same base class, so I've been trying to deserialize them with a binder of types, but that from what I can tell requires a property naming the type.

```
            JsonSerializerSettings jsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
            SerializationBinder = this.knownTypesBinder,
        };


BaseCosmosDBDocument baseCosmosDBDocument = (BaseCosmosDBDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payload, jsettings);
```

This of course results in an exception of not being able to deserialize JsonObject to BaseCosmosDbDocument (or it's derived classes)

I'm looking to use a single Observer Class that can either be instantiate with the target class type or able to determine the target class type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to figure this out, thinking about it, there's only an implicit contract between the observer jsons and the adls processing of those jsons.  As a result I used a regex expression to isolate the Collection Name from the ChangeFeed Context as the data type signal.  That signal was then used to route the files accordingly for processing

```
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(\w+$)");
        var observerCollection = rx.Match(context.FeedResponse.ContentLocation);
```